# Embedded music player does not initially load images and music into main site

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6, onload

I've recreated a music player which I love, love, love, but when I embed it as an html page in the main site the images and music do not initially load. To load you have to click the next or back track button which is not what I want but I can't figure what to do. Any help would be great as I am still a novice and thanks in advance.

This is part of the player js

```
//gen-plr_12-06-22.js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper"),
musicImg = wrapper.querySelector(".img-area img"),
musicName = wrapper.querySelector(".song-details .name"),
musicAlbum = wrapper.querySelector(".song-details .album"),
musicArtist = wrapper.querySelector(".song-details .artist"), 
mainAudio = wrapper.querySelector("#main-audio"),
playPauseBtn = wrapper.querySelector(".play-pause"),
prevBtn = wrapper.querySelector("#prev"),
nextBtn = wrapper.querySelector("#next"),
progressArea = wrapper.querySelector(".progress-area"),
progressBar = wrapper.querySelector(".progress-bar"),
musicList = wrapper.querySelector(".music-list"),
showMoreBtn = wrapper.querySelector("#more-music"),
hideMusicBtn = musicList.querySelector("#close");

let musicIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * allMusic.length) + 1);

window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  loadMusic(musicIndex); //calling load music function once window loaded
  playingNow()
});

//load music function******this is where it looses the info in page on full site
function loadMusic(indexNumb){
  musicName.innerText = allMusic[indexNumb -1].name;
  musicAlbum.innerText = allMusic[indexNumb -1].album;
  musicArtist.innerText = allMusic[indexNumb - 1].artist;
  musicImg.src = `jj-pix/mus-pix/cvs/${allMusic[indexNumb - 1].img}.png`;
  mainAudio.src = `jj-snd/${allMusic[indexNumb - 1].src}.mp3`;
}

//gen-muslist_12-06-22.js
let allMusic = [
  {
    name: "1. 2tech-audio-event",
    album: "Genalbum",
    artist: "Gen",
    img: "genpx",
    src: "2tech-audio-event"
  },
  {
    name: "2. alex-productions-sexy-sax",
    album: "Gen 1album",
    artist: "Gen 1",
    img: "genpx1",
    src: "alex-productions-sexy-sax"
  },
  {
    name: "3. mixaund-team-spirit",
    album: "Gen 2album",
    artist: "Gen 2",
    img: "genpx2",
    src: "mixaund-team-spirit"
  },
  {
    name: "8. Good Lord Willin and the Creeks Don’t Rise",
    album: "Forever On The Run",
    artist: "Jeff Jirout",
    //album: "Gen 3album",
    //artist: "Gen 3",
    img: "genpx3",
    src: "2tech-audio-event"
  },
  {
    name: "5. mixaund-team-spirit",
    album: "Gen 4album",
    artist: "Gen 4",
    img: "genpx4",
    src: "mixaund-team-spirit"
  },
  {
    name: "5. mixaund-team-spirit",
    album: "Gen album",
    artist: "Gen",
    img: "genpx",
    src: "mixaund-team-spirit"
  }
]
```

this is the main site js

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
  navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
})

document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link").forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", () => {
  hamburger.classList.remove("active");
  navMenu.classList.remove("active");
}))

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    var header = document.querySelector("header");
    header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0, 0);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    //$( '#home' ).load( "gen-home_11-29-22.html" );
    $( '#music' ).load( "gen-plr_12-06-22.html" );
    $( '#about' ).load( "about_Lorem11-12-20.html" );
    $( '#contact' ).load( "contact_Lorem11-14-22.html" );
});

// The function actually applying the offset
function offsetAnchor() {
  if (location.hash.length !== 0) {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 75);
  }
}

// Captures click events of all a elements with href starting with #
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(event) {
  // Click events are captured before hashchanges. Timeout
  // causes offsetAnchor to be called after the page jump.
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    offsetAnchor();
  }, 0);
});

// Set the offset when entering page with hash present in the url
window.setTimeout(offsetAnchor, 0);
/*$(document.body).scrollTop($('#music').offset().top);*/

/*$(document.body).animate({
    'scrollTop':   $('#music').offset().top
}, 200);*/

//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("top");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the html? can't execute without it

Comment: sorry for the delay. It would be difficult to provide all of the html, css and js docs for this. There are several and it would take to much space. Thanks for looking into.

Comment: Just the HTML would be enough, so I don't need to create all the elements that your code target, for example `wrapper` `img-area`

Comment: There are actually 3 htmls. It isn't the player html that is the ploblem. It is when the player html is loaded into the main html that the images and musics do not load.